# como guardar en el disco duro un stream mediante conexion rtsp en c#

Tags: c#, stream, real-time

actualmente estoy realizando un programa con c# que pueda copiar localmente el video que se visualiza por protocolo rtsp, he probado con VideoLan DotNet for WinForm pero este no me guarda en el disco aun cuando le paso las opciones con **:sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=C:\Users\hsilva\Desktop\123.mp4}**

alguien ha implementado este tipo de soluciones que me pueda ayudar,

gracias.